# Set a div's height based on another div's height which is defined with overflow hidden

Tags: jquery, css

What I need is set a div's height according with another div's height which is defined on css with `overflow= hidden`.

I'll explain it better.

I have 2 divs placed side by side. The left `div` has `overflow=hidden` so it will stretch vertically based on the size of the image that is inside him and which size is defined with percentage. 
What I need is to set the right div with exactly the same height of the left div.

I'm using jquery but when I use the method `.height()` on the left div, it returns always zero, even if I use it on page load, or document ready or window load, whatever...

```
var H = $("#div1").height();
$("#div2").css("height", H);
```

Please help me!!

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: use scrollHeight property. And please provide all relevant code and a jsfiddle would be a 'plus'

Comment: "that is inside him" ooo kinky. Also can you not use `display: table;` for this?

Comment: @Ruddy That's so "ruddy"

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way:**

```
var hei=$('#divid1')[0].scrollHeight;

$("#divid2").css("min-height",hei);
```